# Which plant is this one?

Tags: identification

A friend received this plant as a present and we are trying to figure out which kind it is, and how to best take care of it. So any tips in that regard will be welcome :)

[image: unidentified plant]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a Bromeliad.  I recently discovered these steps.  I think they make it clear on how to take care of your friends new plant;

- Provide bright light without direct sun exposure.
- Maintain optimal humidity.
- Keep air flowing around the plants.
- Make sure the plants stay moist but not soggy.
- Provide adequate drainage.
- Fertilize sparingly.

[Bromeliad Care](https://www.bromeliads.info/general-indoor-outdoor-bromeliad-care/)

Start by removing the decorative plastic cover.  It will capture and hold water.  You can keep it, if your firend is good a dumping out the water on a regular basis, but most people are not.

Create humidity, by placing a saucer under your pot that is full of pebbles.  After you add the pebbles add water.  The water will evaporate and create humidity around your pot.   I find terra-cotta pots create more humidity, because the pores in the clay breath letting water out through evaporation.

Make sure the soil is very well draining.  That it has plenty of perlite in the potting mix.  Most indoor potting soil should do.  But, adding additional perlite will not hurt.  The soil it is in is probably almost completely just peat with little to no perlite.  That is how it grow best in the greenhouse, but not in your home.

Make sure your pot has holes in the bottom!!!